# What kind of statistical test do I use when controlling for order effects?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, counterbalancing

I have two conditions indoor and outdoor and I show one half of the participants first a picture of meat and then a picture of vegan food and the other half first a picture of vegan food and then a picture of meat.

The dependent variable I measure is what they want to pay for it (willingness to pay). My question is what kind of statistical test I use for this design.

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/597665/whats-the-best-method-for-analyzing-this-experiment-data/597794#597794) help?

Comment: Did you vary the order in which the pictures were prompted? i.e. assign half to meat then vegan, the other half to vegan then meat?